# I have a question about the source, 'multipelx async iterator' of Deno standard library

Tags: javascript, standard-library, deno, multiplexing, async-iterator

What is purpose of `iteratorCount` in the following code (from https://deno.land/std@0.64.0/async/mux_async_iterator.ts)?

```
#iteratorCount = 0
#yields = []
#throws = []
#signal = deferred()

add () {
  ++this.#iteratorCount
  this.#callIteratorNext(iterator)
}

async #callIteratorNext (iterator) {
  try {
    const { value, done } = await iterator.next()
    if (done) {
      --this.#iteratorCount
    } else {
      this.#yields.push({ iterator, value })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    this.#throws.push(e)
  }
  this.#signal.resolve()
}

async *iterate () {
  while (this.#iteratorCount > 0) {
    await this.#signal

    for (let i = 0; i < this.#yields.length; i++) {
      const { iterator, value } = this.#yields[i]
      yield value

      this.#callIteratorNext(iterator)
    }

    if (this.#throws.length) {
      for (const e of this.#throws) {
        throw e
      }
      this.#throws.length = 0
    }

    this.#yields.length = 0
    this.#signal = deferred()
  }
}
```

As far as I see, there's nothing to do with `iteratorCount` if there is no error in all of the iterators added to MuxIterator.

Also, the concept of "not clearing the `iteratorCount` after an errorhandling" and "loop `while (this.iteratorCount > 0)`" seems very weird to me.

I've concluded that this kind of stuff is for "manual error handling", in order to make Mux Async Iterator iterates furthermore by adding additional iterators.

Despite that view, I can't think of a situation where `iteratorCount` go back to zero.

The only way we can decrease the count is to `callIteratorNext()` and make it done.
But, we have to add iterator before it, which makes the count increase.

So, I can't get any role of `iteratorCount`.

Comment: "*The only way we can decrease the count is to callIteratorNext() and make it done. But, we have to add iterator before it, which makes the count increase.*" - yes, the count is incremented when you add an iterator, then it loops until the iterator is done, which makes the count decrement. When all iterators are done, the `iteratorCount` reaches 0 again.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for helping me. (also editting my question.) I owe you.